# Illustrator stroke weight

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Adobe Illustrator: Is it possible to add a custom stroke size (weight) into basic palette which starts with 0,25pt - 0,5pt - etc?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please make sure to review our [help](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) to see how best to use this site. In regards to your question, have you thought about using Illustrator's Graphic Styles feature to save custom presets of the stroke weights you want?

Comment: Hi St Filo, can you please clarify wether you want to *permanently* add weights to the stroke palette (which I read the question as), or simply change the stroke weight of an object to something other than the predefined weights?

Answer (score 1):

Just click the stroke weight in the tool bar at the top of the window and enter you desired weight in any measurement (you can enter cm or mm even if it is set to pt).

[image]

Or you can use the Stroke menu.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add your own value to the stroke palette manually. You would need a [plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/plug-ins.html) for that. If you want to change the stroke weight of an existing object to a custom value that is not already offered, just select the object, and in the top bar type in the custom value in the **Stroke** numeric input.

[image]

Or open the **Stroke** window. and type in the value there.

[image]

Comment: I think you would need a plugin rather than a script, a script runs a set of actions rather than permanently adding to the gui like a plugin can. I believe.

Comment: @CAI, You're right. Thanks! I edited my answer.

Comment: @CAI, Yes, I want to permanently add weights to the stroke palette.

Answer (score 0):

As others have posted, you *can't* edit the increments in the Stroke Panel, but you can set the `Default` paint style to start with a custom stroke weight.

You can **create custom startup profiles** that have strokes set to something specific. Essentially, you alter teh startup documents and set things how you want them... then save. So every time you open a *new* file with that document profile, you get the initial settings you want. While this doesn't make *changing* the stroke weight later any easier... it can let you *start* with a custom weight.

In fact, you don't even *really* need to edit the startup profiles....

You can create several default **Graphic Styles** that merely alter stroke weights to custom amounts. That would make editing stroke weights just a single click. Graphic Styles are *meant* to hold commonly used settings, that's their entire reason for having a panel.

--------- edit for 2021 ---------

Link rot has altered this answer considerably. 
Here's a new link for 2021.. hopefully it lasts a while.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKBMhJcUuj0