# Is there a better way with gradients in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

Although I am an experienced designer, there is something I always struggle with and I feel it is something that subconsciously makes me hate working with or creating vector art and graphics. I struggle with gradients and the way they work or the way I think they work. Maybe I don't understand Illustrator but that's how I go about it.

[image]

The real QUESTION: Is there a better way to create gradients? I usually make some logo and I avoid gradients in logos, so I never researched if there is a better way to color these gradients. I feel there is and I need your help because what I do is confusing me.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the [**help files**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html#:~:text=Create%20and%20apply%20a%20linear%20gradient,-To%20create%20a&text=Click%20the%20Gradient%20tool%20and,Gradient%20panel%2C%20click%20Linear%20Gradient.). It's possible drag from the color or swatches panels to gradient stops, one can double-click a gradient stop, you can choose the color *palette* rather than the color *books* in the gradient panel, etc. I'm sure someone will post a "lesson in gradients", but all the information regarding basic operations is in the help files.

Comment: @Scott Really? Maybe we should write this "it's all in the help files" and close StackExchange. The funny thing is in the help you link, they say to pick a color from the available swatches but they are limited. When I click the stop of the gradient it offers Grayscale picker. I need to switch to RGB but as I demonstrated, the second stop is also Grayscale and I find it weird and strange. That's why I ask for a better way. I counted 9 clicks to get a custom gradient and 4 of them are to switch Grayscale to RGB. Can you create a custom gradient with less than 9 clicks?

Comment: You need to click the color **palette** icon on the Color Panel [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq6eT.png) --This is essentially *basic* operations of the application. This isn't anything overly complicated or in depth. All it takes is an understanding of the *basic* operations. While stack certainly exists to help users, *some* effort should be made by the users to understand their tools. The help files do **exactly** that. Should a user run into difficulty with basic operations, the help files should be the *first* step they take in an effort to resolve their issue.

Comment: And yes, I can create a custom 2-stop gradient with 2 clicks merely because I understand *how* the panels work. It's hopefully *clear* that I participate at this stack only to *help* users. But if Adobe has already set up a very detailed and thorough explanation of something, there's not a great deal of benefit in merely regurgitating that same information.

Comment: @Scott OK, let me explain. Let's say I need a gradient background. I draw my rectangle. I set the fill to gradient. I click the first stop, the color panel changes to Grayscale. Why? IDK. I click the little icon to set RGB and this takes 2 extra clicks. Then click second stop, color panel changes to Grayscale yet again. I set it to RGB again. I get my gradient, I export the thing.

Comment: It's really just a matter of understanding what *can* be done... you don't *have* to click gradient stops. You can [drag/drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wETGf.gif) -- [or from Swatches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlKq1.gif). I *really* don't want to come across as being difficult or obstinate, but this is all detailed in the help files. In fact, there's even a [video tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/gradients.html) on using gradients.All this information from Adobe is *exactly* what you are asking about. The help files cover your issues if you'd merely look at them.

Comment: This is not what I ask. If you follow what I illustrate in the question, you will understand it.

Comment: Okay. I really don't understand the mindset of resisting the help files if they are helpful (they aren't always). I believe they are in this instance.

Comment: @Scott Let me point out the exact problem. When you open a new document and go to the Gradient panel and click the first stop, the Color panel is set to Grayscale. Even when you set it to RGB, the moment you click the second stop, the Color panel will be set to Grayscale again. This means that to create your first gradient with 2 full RGB spectrum colors requires 8-9 clicks.
You say 2 clicks, maybe talking about dragging 2 colors from Swatches, where we find 20-30 colors, not 16.7 million RGB colors.

Comment: The *default* white to black gradient is indeed a greyscale gradient. If you want a different default gradient, you need to [edit the startup documents](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67134/3270) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/120650/3270)

Comment: For me, it's just always been easier to drag a color to the gradient and that problem is solved immediately rather than editing the startup files. Often times I *want* a greyscale gradient.

Comment: @Scott OK, that's already getting us somewhere. I can save a new NEW document and save 4 clicks and that's what I wanted. Now for your dragging ... I don't like dragging colors but even if you do, you spend 2 clicks to drag 2 colors you don't like. This turns the gradient stops into RGB, then 2 clicks per stop is 4 clicks ... so in conclusion, my method takes 8-9 clicks, dragging is taking 6-7 clicks, saving a new template document will get it to 4-5 clicks for real full control and that's what I asked for.
You may want a grayscale gradient but not 2 Grayscale pickers as a default.

Comment: @Komental the benefit of dragging is that you can apply global swatches to your gradients which is very useful for logos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradient Panel will revert to whatever color palette you have specified in the Color Panel. This is why you are having to work around that every time you want to add color your gradient- the Color Panel palette is set to Grayscale.

Simply open the Color Panel and set it to RGB (or whatever) from the hamburger menu in the upper right corner. Then each time you **double** click the color stop the palette that you want will come up.

---

EDIT- After further investigation... I do not use the Gradient Panel this  way- I simply drag a swatch to a color stop then adjust the color sliders from there.

It seems the Color Panel will stay in Grayscale (which is the problem you are having) if the item you had selected previous to that is set to Grayscale. You can have 3 objects- one set to Grayscale in the Color Panel, and one set to RGB. The third object will take on the color palette of whichever one you had previously selected.

Not sure this helps- it almost seems like a bug to me...

---

Another extra- if you prefer the "Photoshop Style" Color Picker (I never use it)- Select the Gradient Tool (or select Edit Gradient from the Gradient Panel). Select one of the color stops (either in the Gradient Panel or on the Gradient Tool itself) and then double click the Fill Box in either the Tool Panel or in the Gradient Panel and the "Color Picker" will open and you can choose your color from there .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The problem is that the default gradient is Grayscale. Both stops are grayscale and they reset the color panel to Grayscale. Your method does seem to work, I click the first stop, Color panel sets to grayscale but if I double click that fill box it does allow me to pick a color for the stop. Weird but true. It doesn't save clicks but it makes more sense + I like the PS color picker. Your method is the best so far and I actually like it. One bad moment is the gradient doesn't change until I press OK, so no preview but it's OK, because usually I know what color hue I want.